# How to prevent onBlur from triggering when clicking on the Cancel link of the modal in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a semantic-ui modal that has a "Cancel" link. Inside the modal I have the form that has an empty but required field in focus. When I click the Cancel link the first time its event is not received. Instead, the required field shows its error saying this field is required. The next Cancel click will go through and close the modal.

How to prevent user from clicking on the Cancel link twice?
I want user to close the modal in one click and not trigger an blur error.

```
handleBlur = (field) => {
  const fieldName = this.getFieldNameToBlur(field);
  const updatedData = {...this.state};
  const entityDataPath = 'context.user';
  this.props.saveEntityData(entityDataPath, '', updatedData, fieldName);
};

getFieldNameToBlur = (fieldName) => {
  const {validationId} = this.props;
  return validationId && fieldName ? `${validationId}.${fieldName}` : false;
};

closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({openModal: MODALS.NONE})
}

<Modal
  parseHtml="true"
  title="Add User"
  size="small"
  open={open}
  disableButton={!validInputs}
  buttonText={'Confirm'}
  confirmButton={'visible'}
  confirmAction={ this.confirmAction() }
>
  <Form id="user-form">
    <InlineTextBoxField
      value={name}
      label={labels[NAME]}
      name={NAME}
      handleChange={(e) => {
        const targetVal = e.target.value;
        this.handleChange(NAME, targetVal);
      }}
      handleBlur={() => this.handleBlur(NAME)}
      displayError={displayError(NAME)}
      errorMessages={errorMessage(NAME)}
    />
    <a
      href="#"
      onClick={this.closeModal}
      title={'Cancel'}
    >
      Cancel
    </a>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple trick for this.

```
this.state = {
  openModal: MODALS.NONE,
  isOpened: false
}
(...)
closeModal = () => {
  if(this.state.isOpened){
    this.setState({ openModal: MODALS.NONE, isOpened: false });
  }
}
openModal = () => {
  if(!this.state.isOpened){
    this.setState({ openModal: MODALS.OPEN_OR_SOMETHING, isOpened: true });
  }
}
```

You can use a state for modal's status like `isOpened`

Comment: this didn't work. I still see the error triggering when clicking on the Cancel link for the first time and modal is still closing on the second click.